# How to batch export raster files from qgis?

Tags: export, batch-processing, raster, qgis

I need to *export->save as* quite a big amount of raster files in qgis and just can't find a way to make it all at once. I'm not very advanced in coding. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Processing Toolbox-->Database--> Package Layers

this way save your all rasters in one gpkg package.